# Jquery localize UTC Date Time

Tags: jquery, date, utc, datetime-conversion

I am trying to localize my date and I am getting NAN invalid date. What would be the mistake?

[My Code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qa7wb7j/)

```
function localizeUTCDateTime(date) {
    var utcdate = new Date(date + " UTC");
    return utcdate.toDateString() + " " + utcdate.getHours() + ":" + utcdate.getMinutes() + ":" + utcdate.getSeconds();
}

var creationDate = '2014-09-23T00:59:26.92';
$('#divTime').text(localizeUTCDateTime(creationDate));


<div id='divTime'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function localizeUTCDateTime(date) {
    var utcdate =new Date(Date.parse(date));
    console.log(utcdate);
    return utcdate.toUTCString() + " " + utcdate.getHours() + ":" + utcdate.getMinutes() + ":" + utcdate.getSeconds();
}

var creationDate = '2014-09-23T00:59:26.92';
$('#divTime').text(localizeUTCDateTime(creationDate));
```

First parse it`Date.parse(date)` then new `Date`. For convert it to string use `utcdate.toUTCString()`.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svx30saL/)